# WCF Service security suggestions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, certificate

I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 application in development that uses a web service to access security information (Roles, Permissions, etc).  The users of these applications will be internal Company users.  This web service security mode is currently set to "None".

What kind of **web service** security do you recommend for my situation?  Should I use certificates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an internal use I suggest using [Windows Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744835%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) :

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear in my original post.  I meant what Security should I use for my web service, not the web application itself.

Comment: @Elim99 - Steven is still correct. You can enforce Windows security on web services as well.

Comment: @Elim99: As M,Babcock said windows authentication is available for an intranet webservice